# Expectation of absolute value

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

I have to show whether the following statement is true or not:

$$E(|x|) \le E(x^2) + 1$$

I started with

$$E(|x|) = 2\int_{0}^\infty xf(x)dx  \le E(x^2) + 1 = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) + f(x)dx $$

but I can't really see how to proceed.

Any helps appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using linearity of expectation,

$$ E(x^2) + E(1) - E(\lvert x\rvert) =  E(x^2 + 1 - \lvert x\rvert). $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. So given that the quadratic equation $x^2 + 1 - |x|$ has no real solution, the inequality $E(x^2 + 1 - |x|) >= 0$ is always verified, is that right?

Comment: Yes: continuous, no real solution, and positive somewhere, implies positive everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** write $|X|$ as $|X|=|X| 1_{\{|X|<1\}}+|X| 1_{\{|X|\geq 1\}}$. Now just use the fact that expectation is linear and monotone.